# How can I use the "Links List" template in Oracle Apex 5.0

Tags: templates, oracle-apex-5

I have a sub region item on a page where I want to show a list of links using the "Links List" template.

What kind of item do I have to create to be able to use the "Links List" template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to go to `Shared Components` -> `Navigation` -> `Lists` and create there a new list (<kbd>Create</kbd> button). There you have to enter a name of the list:

[image]

and pairs of URLs and their labels:

[image]

You can fill it at this moment or later.

Next, you go to the desired page and create a new region with type `List`. In the creation wizard, you enter the name of the region and then choose the list, created in the previous step:

[image]